# Port Address Translation strange behavior: port 80 appears to be open from outside but outside connections do not work

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

This is my configuration:

- Host machine: Windows 10 X64 21H2 (i7 + 64GB ram)
- Hypervisor type 2: VMWare Workstation 16.2.4
- Guest machine: Windows 10 X64 21H2 (16GB ram)
- Modem/Router: Livebox Fibra (ISP Orange Spain – optical fiber) with latest firmware

The guest machine’s nic is configured as bridged so it can obtain its IPv4 address directly from the Livebox Fibra modem.

I downloaded Moodle 4.0.2 (XAMPP portable + Moodle package) and launched it on my guest machine, opening all the necessary ports on Windows Firewall and everything works fine inside LAN, there is no problem to access to Moodle privately, using the private IPv4 address obtained by Livebox Fibra router.

Since I need that this Moodle instance can be accessed from outside my LAN, I created a NAT/PAT rule on my Livebox Fibra modem for forwarding external HTTP (port 80) requests to the guest machine on which Moodle is running on;

using an external service like https://portchecker.co or https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ on the port 80 of the public IP v4 address of router’s public interface, I get that the port is correctly open;

trying to connect, from outside of my LAN, with any browser (Edge, Brave, Firefox, Internet Explorer) to http://routerPublicAddress I cannot access to Moodle getting an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error;

trying to understand the problem, I disabled Windows firewall and antivirus on guest and host machines and disabled Livebox Fibra firewall but nothing changes: external port 80 check is ok (*Port 80 is open on X.X.X.X* say **yougetsignal.com** and **portchecker.co**) but external HTTP requests not working;

I also tried to change external port on Livebox Fibra PAT rule but nothing changes: the new external port is correctly open, using external checker service, but I cannot connect to the web server from outside.

Why HTTP port appears to be open from the outside but external connections do not work? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: When you say "external connections", do you mean _actually_ external connections (i.e. from another location, or even another ISP), or do you mean internal connections from the same place to your own external IP?

Comment: Hi, if I check my port 80, opened on my router using a PAT rule, from outside using a service like https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ or https://portchecker.co/ it is open but even if it is checked as open from outside (from yougetsignal.com or portchecker.co or similar services) i cannot establish an external HTTP connection. I hope I was clear